# Do you gain reputation from upvotes from the meta site

Tags: support, voting, meta, reputation

I just have a simple question: Do you gain any reputation from the upvotes from the meta-site?

Comment: Questions about features of the Stack Exchange network as a whole are still on-topic on per-site metas, especially when they're [support] questions, and even more especially, when the answer is different if this were asked on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (where the answer is "yes, upvotes give rep")

Comment: @caird ok, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No.

I've upvoted your question for you to verify this.

From the [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) page:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Code Golf Stack Exchange (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 1 reputation to participate on meta.